# Use a border within row elements in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap/html and I am trying to border the three alerts in a row. How can I do that? It looks like this so far:

[image]

what I have so far is

```html
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
<div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
</div>
..
```

How can I surround this with a span?

Thank you all

Comment: So you are trying to surround the three alerts with a box? You already have a `<div class="container">`. Have you tried adding a CSS style to that div?

Comment: the simple way is that add `border-primary` to every alert box

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque yes want to sorround them with a box.

Answer (score 1):

sorry I'm just seeing your follow up question. You could add some padding with css. CSS can be added to HTML elements: Inline - by using the style attribute in HTML elements Internal - by using a  element in the  section

`.alert-primary { 
   padding: 30px; }`

This would add just a simple border around each alert thru bootstrap
As well as the below changes to the class of

`<div class="alert alert-primary">`

---

```html
<style>
  .alert-primary {
    padding: 30px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container border border-dark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="alert alert-primary"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but how can I implement that in my code to make it work?

Comment: If you are already using bootstrap and have it linked into your html file, you should be able to add it just as you added all the other <div> tags

Comment: Edited to show how to apply required css classes to code in question.

Comment: @Elizabeth I edited the picture in the question. Now it looks like this. 
it's almost correct. How can I make the distance to the border?

Comment: Hi Lia, sorry I'm just seeing your follow up question. You could add some padding with css.

CSS can be added to HTML elements:

Inline - by using the style attribute in HTML elements
Internal - by using a   `<style> element in the <head> **.alert-primary {
  padding: 30px;
}**`

Comment: I think the question was edited and the bootstrap link is no longer there to allow the `run code snippet` to function and show an example of the new code.